# Unable to run a basic Sonar analysis from MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner

Tags: sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I am sure I am missing something but unable to figure out what.

The following commands are executed via the VS2015 command prompt.

```
D:\Sonar\Project1\msbuild\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"FC" /n:"FC" /v:"1.0"
msbuild.exe D:\Sonar\Project1\FC.sln
D:\Sonar\Project1\msbuild\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
```

The sonar-project.properties file that gets automatically created in the out directory under .sonarqube folder shows the following

```
E0566501-CF6F-454A-88CA-6AEFEA7D0EBC.sonar.projectKey=FC:E0566501-CF6F-454A-88CA-6AEFEA7D0EBC
E0566501-CF6F-454A-88CA-6AEFEA7D0EBC.sonar.projectName=FC
E0566501-CF6F-454A-88CA-6AEFEA7D0EBC.sonar.projectBaseDir=D:\\Sonar\\Project1\\FC
E0566501-CF6F-454A-88CA-6AEFEA7D0EBC.sonar.sources=\
D:\\Sonar\\Project1\\FileComparison\\Form1.cs,\
.
.
E0566501-CF6F-454A-88CA-6AEFEA7D0EBC.sonar.stylecop.projectFilePath=D:\\Sonar\\Project1\\FC\\FC.csproj

sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.visualstudio.enable=false

sonar.projectKey=FC
sonar.projectName=FC
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.projectBaseDir=D:\\Sonar\\Project1\\FC
sonar.working.directory=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\.sonarqube\\out\\.sonar

# FIXME: Encoding is hardcoded
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.modules=E0566501-CF6F-454A-88CA-6AEFEA7D0EBC
```

[Screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBJQh.png)

Comment: Please provide more information about what isn't working. What does the console output say? Is it reporting any errors? Is a project being created in the SonarQube server?
The fact that the properties file is being produced suggests that the pre-build and build steps have worked correctly.
FYI the commands need to be run from a VS command prompt, but I'd recommend changing the directory from *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0* before running them: you don't really want to have all of the temporary analysis files created under *Program Files*.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback. The screenshot of the console output is attached. The project is not created on sonar server. Please help

Comment: It looks like the SonarGraph/hello2morrow plugin is throwing an exception. Try disabling the plugin.

Comment: Thanks a ton duncanpMS! I feel stupid to have missed the error. I ran into another issue now. I am unable to run this via Teamcity since they do not support the new version of SonarRunner yet and all other workarounds failed as I cannot get Visual Studio installed on my CI server due to licensing issue.